# Is it possible to get .NET 4.0 on the server without having to install it?

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is it possible to get .NET 4.0 on the server without having to install it?  Well! It may sound crazy by just reading the title without actually going into it.

My senior developers(who used to do VB6/ASP programming back then) doesnt want .NET 4.0 on the server for two reasons. 1) They fear that all their existing applications will break. 2) They will be forced to learn new technologies which they dont want.

But unfortunately they are the senior programmers(by age) and are the decision makers.So here is my crazy thought. Is it possible to get .NET framework running on the server without having  to install it. What I mean by that is, If I deploy all the .NET 4.0 dlls in the GAC of the server and to add some values into registry. Will I be able to run .NET 4.0 apps on it?

or can we have only certain applications use .NET 4.0 run time and the old applications use .NET 2.0/or 1.1 run time?

The current .NET version on the server is .NET 3.5 SP1. Any suggestions & ideas are welcomed?

Please dont consider it as a duplicate question because I am not asking for .NET 2.0 framework as did by earlier posts. I am asking specifically for .NET 4.0 which has not been posted yet.

Comment: Keep in mind that the .Net Framework 4 is still in pre-release

Comment: Yes! I dont want it on server now but want it in April/May after the official release. Until then I will test with VS2010/.NET 4.0 RC release on a development server.

Comment: Is installing .NET 4.0 in to dev to prove existing VB6/ASP applications won't break not an option?

Comment: @funwithcoding: So why do you want to mess with "your" developers' most important tool. Wouldn't it be easier to setup a new machine or a virtual one configured with 4.0 so you can safely try it out?

Comment: @Fredrik, Unfortunately that is not an option. All the applications have to be deployed to the allotted servers.

Comment: @Faisal, Well thats not entirely true. I do remember when some IT guy upgraded the .NET framework 2.0 to 3.5. Lot of old web applications broke because they used classic ASP constructs within their applications targeting .net 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding .NET 4.0 is independent. For example to install .NET 3.5 you would need the 2.0 runtime already installed, but I'm under the impression that .Net 4.0 can be installed independently.

Another things is that application built for previous version will not be run in the .NET 4.0 runtime. You would need to recompile these applications to target .NET 4.0. This statement is confirmed in MSDN ([.NET 4.0 Application Compatibility and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28VS.100%29.aspx#application_compatibility_and_deployment)).

So in you scenario after installing .NET 4.0, in you server, only applications built to specifically target it would be running in the 4.0 runtime.

Comment: Finally some good news coming from you Joao Angelo. Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: +1. Yes, IIS can run .Net 1.x, 2.0-3.5, and 4.0 applications independently. A 3.5 application will _not_ use the 4.0 runtime unless you want it to. Nothing will break.

Comment: @lucas: can I quote you on that? Nothing ever breaks when installing fresh MS RTMs? lol. joking...

Answer (score 6):

No. not in any dependable working order no. And it would be foolish to try.

This is one of the reasons you should give deference to you seniors whether you agree with them or not. For one, they have apparently been through enought microsoft betas to know that
you don't install an ms beta (and sometimes pre sp1 ;-]) on a production server, whether they say it is go-live or not.

Just. Don't. Do. It.

The concern, whether you or I agree, is twofold: 1) will installing it break anything that isn't broken? impossible to know without taking the step and 2) what happens @ RTM? You generally have to uninstall the *beta* to install the gold. Will that break anything? impossible to know until it happens.

You summation of their reasons demonstrates a bit of immaturity and dare I say, impetuosity. This will serve you well neither short or long term in any scenario. I say so from experience.

So, ask if there is a box in the boneyard you can slap an OS and 4.0 on to use as a test machine. Get your current apps working with 3.5 and image it. then install 4.0 and develop and observe and check the state of the existing codebase that pays your salary.

When 4.0 goes gold, reimage the box with the working image you made previously and repeat.

THEN go to the higher ups with an informed request and supporting data/experience.

just my 2 pesos. take it or leave it.

Comment: @Sky, Ofcourse I am not going to have .NET beta on production servers. I want do it( if at all possible) only after .NET 4.0 release and only if there is a safe way to do it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I am failed to understand why "They fear that all their existing applications will break"?? I always thought that different versions of .NET framework can co-exist without any problem.

Comment: "thought" is the operative word here. In order to install .NET 3.5, you need .NET 2.0 SP1, which is not 100% backwards compatible with .NET 2.0 (pre-SP1). I can understand their fear, I've been there before.

Comment: @Lasse - Yes it's a fear, but it's unfounded.  The frameworks are installed side-by-side, .net 3.5 in installed in a 3.5 directory (even though it's 2.0 SP1).  Plus if the existing apps are VB6/Classic ASP then the install of .NET doesn't matter a damn

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework was designed to be able to support side-by-side frameworks running independently of each other:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/techinfo/serverroles/appserver/mngfrmwk.mspx

E.g. The .NET 1.0 framework has a completely different compiler, runtime, class libraries, GAC, etc to the .NET 2.0+ framework. Code that was built to use the .NET 1.0 framework will continue to do so. The .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 frameworks however both use the .NET 2.0 runtime with added libraries for each version.

.NET 4.0 is a completely new release so your previous .NET versions will remain unaffected. .NET 4.0 also include a new In-Process Side-by-side feature which lets the same .NET 4 process to use different installed versions of the .NET framework side-by-side:

http://blogs.msdn.com/clrteam/archive/2009/06/03/in-process-side-by-side-part1.aspx

Essentially, in theory it should be fine to install .NET 4.0 and it won't affect the any of the previous versions however I would hold off until the final release comes out to save you from re-installing it, etc.